# How to create a new vector where each element must be calculated from many vectors?

Tags: c++

I have a join_function which takes two elements and saves the result by updating the calling element. For example, if I have three initial elements A, B and C and one later element D, I can use the following code.

```
for (auto it = begin, et = end; it!=et; ++it)
{
 later_element N = *it;
 D.join_function(N);
}
```

The above code will join A and D, saves the result to D. Then joins B and D and saves the result to D and so on. The for loop iterates over all later elements.

Now, my problem is how to handle the same with vectors. I do not know if there will be 3 such later element vectors or more or less but the for loop is able to iterate over them. The size of vectors can be power of 2: 1 or 2 or 4 or 8 and so on. For example, if A is of size 2, B is of size 4, C is of size 1 and D is of size 2, the new result vector (say) E will have size 16.

E[0] will be created by joining A[0]D[0], B[0]D[0] and C[0]D[0]. E[1] will be A[0]D[0], B[1]D[0] and C[0]D[0]. E[2] will be A[0]D[0], B[2]D[0] and C[0]D[0] and so on till B is covered. Then similarly A will be covered. Of course the order is not fixed and first A and then B and then C can be covered. Once all later elements are covered using D[0], same must be repeated for D[1] and so on for all D elements. I call D as initial element. So its loop is obvious to me but the covering of later element vectors is not clear. The below code is clear to me when initial_element is the D vector.

```
for (long i=0; i< initial_element.size(); ++i)
{
  for (auto it = begin, et = end; it!=et; ++it)
  {
    later_vector later = *it;
  }
}
```

Comment: If you're talking about `std::vector`, you simply "join" vectors by using `std::vector<T>::insert`.  There is no need to write any loops.

Comment: Is `later_vector` a type and `later` an object of that type? You are creating an object over and over but doing nothing with it. This can't be what you intend.

Comment: Can you rewrite your `join_function` so that it results in a new object, rather than modifying it's first argument? i.e. instead of `d += a`, you have `auto e = d + a` if the operation were `+`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I am indeed talking about `std::vector` but insert only works if I already have the elements that I want to insert into the vector. Currently the problem is that I do not know how to calculate the elements from different vector elements.

Comment: @doug later_vector is indeed a type and later is an object. I have not given any more code inside the loop because I could not think of any way to calculate the elements and insert them to a new vector. The code is not complete from any aspect. I only gave code that I think is correct and will be required in a correct version of code which will add more loops after creation of the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store intermediate results, and loop over one input vector at a time.

```
using Elems = std::vector</* Your element type*/>;

Elems combine(const Elems & acc, const Elems & next) {
    Elems result;
    for (auto a : acc) {
        for (auto n : next) {
            result.push_back(a.join(n));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then to combine them all is [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate)

```
int main() {
    std::vector<Elems> inputs = { A, B, C, D }; // or whatever
    Elems E = std::accumulate(inputs.rbegin() + 1, inputs.rend(), inputs.back(), combine);
}
```

Comment: Currently the later_vectors and initial_element vector are not in a vector. But I think that I can put them in a vector if required. But will it work if I put the initial_element vector in place of inputs.back() and inputs.rbegin() without increment after putting the later_vectors in the inputs vector? But I am not sure how the combine function will get the parameters in that case because its both parameters have `&` and also there is no return statement in `combine`.

Comment: `combine` is called by `std::accumulate` here, once for each item in the range it is given (3 times in the example, `C`, `B` then `A`)

Comment: Yes, if `initial_element` is a separate variable you can just use it directly as the third argument. I just assumed "later_vectors" was a collection because you referred to it by name.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you think the combine function should return a reference like `return &result`?

Comment: Also I have now modified the accumulate like this. Elems E = std::accumulate(pre_begin(s), pre_end(s), *initial_element, combine); Here pre_begin(s) gives an iterator which I can use to obtain the vector A and pre_end(s) gives the iterator which can be used to get C. So, instead of reverse iteration, I am using forward iteration. I hope that it should work.

Comment: But I have a problem if combine is a separate function. The join_function needs the object `s` for computation like this `a.join(s, n)` considering `a` and `n` are still used as given in your answer. Is there any way to pass this object to combine? This object is of different type than the vectors and it is created just before I am calling `std::accumulate`.